# Losing the header of a csv file after normlizing

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I've wrote the following code to read a csv file run a column wise normalization :

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# reading Train values
Training ='Training.csv'
df       = pd.read_csv(Training)
df =df.drop(df.columns[len(df.loc[1])-1],axis=1)
df =df.drop(df.columns[len(df.loc[1])-1],axis=1)  
df.describe()
minmax_scaler= preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
np_scaled = minmax_scaler.fit_transform(df)
normalized = pd.DataFrame(np_scaled)
normalized.describe()
np.shape(df)
np.shape(normalized)
```

My question is why I can't see the headers in the `normalized` list?  despite it having the same shape of `df`, I've tried to read the csv file without a header but the program crashes ?

```
..............................
df       = pd.read_csv(Training,header=None)
.........................
```

delivers the following :

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-dd18ba2a6204> in <module>()
     14 df.describe()
     15 minmax_scaler= preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
---> 16 np_scaled = minmax_scaler.fit_transform(df)
     17 normalized = pd.DataFrame(np_scaled)
     18 normalized.describe()

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    492         if y is None:
    493             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 494             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    495         else:
    496             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in fit(self, X, y)
    290         # Reset internal state before fitting
    291         self._reset()
--> 292         return self.partial_fit(X, y)
    293 
    294     def partial_fit(self, X, y=None):

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in partial_fit(self, X, y)
    316 
    317         X = check_array(X, copy=self.copy, ensure_2d=False, warn_on_dtype=True,
--> 318                         estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
    319 
    320         if X.ndim == 1:

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    380                                       force_all_finite)
    381     else:
--> 382         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    383 
    384         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Feature458'
```

I'll greatful for any hint about how may I solve this !

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is because you use `preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()` which returns an array, not a dataframe.
After you create a dataframe based on this matrix, it does not know anything about your columns.

You could try something like

```
normalized = pd.DataFrame(np_scaled, columns=df.columns)
```

And with the latter example (with `header=False`), you simply have your header as the first row. When sklearn tries to convert a column name into an integer, you get your error.